# VBA to send email via Lotus Notes 6.5 with Attachment

Tags: excel, lotus-notes, vba

I have big problem.
I have macro to send multiple emails from Excel via Lotus Notes 6.5

The code of my macro is:

```
Public Function SendNotesMail()
'This public sub will send a mail and attachment if neccessary to the recipient including the body text.
'Requires that notes client is installed on the system.

'Set up the objects required for Automation into lotus notes

Dim Subject As String
Dim Attachment As String
Dim Recipient As String
Dim BodyText As String
Dim SaveIt As Boolean
Dim Maildb As Object 'The mail database
Dim UserName As String 'The current users notes name
Dim MailDbName As String 'THe current users notes mail database name
Dim MailDoc As Object 'The mail document itself
Dim AttachME As Object 'The attachment richtextfile object
Dim Session As Object 'The notes session
Dim EmbedObj As Object 'The embedded object (Attachment)
Dim EmailSend As Object
Dim EmailApp As Object

'Start a session to notes

Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")

'Get the sessions username and then calculate the mail file name.
'You may or may not need this as for MailDBname with some systems you can pass an empty string
UserName = Session.UserName
MailDbName = Left$(UserName, 1) & Right$(UserName, (Len(UserName) - InStr(1, UserName, " "))) & ".nsf"

'Open the mail database in notes
Set Maildb = Session.GETDATABASE("", MailDbName)
If Maildb.IsOpen = True Then
'Already open for mail
Else
Maildb.OPENMAIL
End If

'Set up the new mail document
Set MailDoc = Maildb.CREATEDOCUMENT
MailDoc.Form = "Memo"
MailDoc.sendto = "admin@tlen.pl"
MailDoc.Subject = "TDBank Validation File"
MailDoc.Body = "Here is your TDBank Validation File for today."
MailDoc.SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = SaveIt

'Set up the embedded object and attachment and attach it

If Attachment <> "" Then
Set AttachME = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM.Add("H:\Document\1.pdf")
Set EmbedObj = AttachME.EMBEDOBJECT(1454, "", Attachment, "H:\Document\1.pdf")
MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM ("H:\Document\1.pdf")

End If

'Send the document
MailDoc.Send 0, Recipient

'Clean Up
Set Maildb = Nothing
Set MailDoc = Nothing
Set AttachME = Nothing
Set Session = Nothing
Set EmbedObj = Nothing

End Function
```

And problem is that attachments is not assigned to email when i receiving it. I did not get any error or sth like that. Just only email without attachment.

File 1.pdf is in the same folder as my xls with VBA.

Could You please help me.

Answer (score 2):

0. It is not clear in your code where you `Attachment` variable is filled by value. Make sure that this value is not empty.
1. According to documentation you can specify only `type%` and `source$` parameters for [`EmbedObject`](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/97ae851a5d60298685256c54004d2c18?OpenDocument) method:

```vb
Set notesEmbeddedObject = notesRichTextItem.EmbedObject(1454, "", "H:\Document\1.pdf")
```

2. You can use `Body` field to embed an object:

```vb
'Your code

Set MailDoc = Maildb.CREATEDOCUMENT
MailDoc.Form = "Memo"
MailDoc.sendto = "admin@example.com"
MailDoc.Subject = "TDBank Validation File"
MailDoc.SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = SaveIt

Dim richTextItem As Object
Set richTextItem = MailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("Body")
richTextItem.AppendText("Here is your TDBank Validation File for today.")

If Attachment <> "" Then
    richTextItem.EmbedObject(1454, "", "H:\Document\1.pdf")
End If

'Your code
```